# Communication for far away satellites

Tags: communication

Today in the tech age we have many communication technologies cell tower for cell  phones,  wifi, nuclear subs have some classified method of communication,  etc.  What communication technology is being used if a satellite probe is sent past Jupiter & transmits a signal back to scientists to monitor progress or review high definition detailed images?

Comment: The "tech age" goes back way before cell phones. :-)

Comment: This question would be better asked on the "space exploration" stack exchange.

Comment: Jupiter distance isn't so hard, but the farther a ship gets the weaker the signal.   The end result is that transmission becomes slower.   Messages can still be received, but the signal strength determins the speed of information transfer.   At Pluto distance, the rate of transmission is less than the slowest dial up modem.  It takes a few minutes to transmit a single image.

Answer (score 4):

That's the job of NASA's [Deep Space Network](https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov), plus sites in other countries that perform similar functions. NASA currently has facilities in California, Spain, and Australia whose primary function is to communicate with devices sent beyond low Earth orbit.

In addition to these Deep Space Network sites, NASA and the US Department of Defense jointly operate the [Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_and_Data_Relay_Satellite_System) network. This system comprises geosynchronous satellites outfitted with communications equipment, relay stations in White Sands, New Mexico and in Guam, plus a control station in Greenbelt, Maryland. The European Space Agency has developed a similar system that takes advantage of recent developments in long distance laser communications. These satellite-based systems are intended for use by vehicles near the Earth. More remote vehicles such as probes to Mars, Venus, and beyond generally use the Deep Space Network.